# Do Crossing Laser Beams Affect Their Associated Photosensors?

Tags: laser

I am working on a baseball pitching target. The "target" will be made of a grid of Laser emitters and photosensitive receivers. I'm wondering if I should "offset" the X axis from the Y axis so that one is behind the other and the beams never crosss.. If they are all lined up on the same plane, an X beam would cross 11 Y beams before reaching its associated receiver. A Y beam would cross 16 X beams. That seems problematic to me but I just don't know.

Any insight would be most helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: ChemiCalChem's answer about covers it. I would add one obvious but generally overlooked observation to this: if light were not a linear phenomenon, then the scattering of light on other light would make the universe look foggy. Starlight could never reach us because it would be completely dispersed by the sunlight that is all around us. That shadows (like Earth's shadow, which gives us "night") exist proves that (visible) light can, for all practical purposes, not interact with itself. It's a different matter for ultra-high energy gamma quanta, but that's a different question.

Comment: @FlatterMann also makes an excellent point that I thought about while typing up the answer. There are so many light rays bouncing around and only a tiny amount of them ever manage to reach your eyes. The fact that there is a lot of background electromagnetic radiation doesn't seem to affect our ability to see at all, and that's quite nifty, I would say.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems It is probably no coincidence that physics initially developed alongside astronomy. I can't even imagine what inhabitants of a universe that suffers from eternally bright skies would have to do. They couldn't have the equivalents of a Copernicus, Galileo, Kepler or Newton...

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's equations are linear in the fields, meaning solutions to them obey the superposition principle.

In particular, this means beams of light crossing each other don't affect one another, much like sound waves crossing each other in air.

It is only at extremely high electromagnetic field strengths that non-linear effects start to arise, way way above what a laser beam is capable of producing.

Comment: Lasers are perfectly capable of generating various non-linear effects...

Comment: @JonCuster Not in vacuum, though. To reach gamma-gamma scattering experimentally takes a custom designed electron synchrotron x-ray source in addition to a really strong optical laser. So while you are not "incorrect", for the purposes of all optical regimes accessible to the average person (and the average physicist) light is a perfectly linear phenomenon. The main educational problem IMHO is to make people understand the consequence of that linearity. You can still find the "single particle double slit" plastered all over the media. Even real physicists are talking about that nonsense.

Comment: So, it sounds like a Y axis beam passing through multiple X axis beams should have no problem reaching its receiver.... At least that's what I'm gathering from the  comments here!

Comment: @FlatterMann - true, but air and other gases do yield nonlinear effects fairly readily. As one of my mentors once said, you hit anything hard enough and it will go nonlinear...

Comment: @JonCuster I am in full agreement with your mentor. I will ask for an air ionizing pulse laser and a pair of extra dark safety goggles for next Christmas.

Comment: @JonCuster I wouldn't consider air to be a non-linear medium at the electromagnetic field strength involved in OP's setup. There don't appear to be non-linear effects even in some crazy laser Youtube videos like the ones by Brainiac75. I doubt this person is dealing with lasers powerful enough to ionize air. I'd like to see one of those, though, do you have a link to one available to general consumers?

Comment: @JonCuster The idea just occurred to me that you might also be referring to light-air scattering, but those effects are inevitable in the first place. I think what's important to discuss here is light-light scattering, and those processes only happen at ultra-high energy scales.